# Do I have to open source a website if I use GPL-licensed blogging software?

Tags: gpl, website

My friend is building a website for a school newspaper and we were considering using [Instant Press](https://code.google.com/archive/p/instant-press/) for the stories to show up. Instant Press is licensed with the GPL 2.

If we use Instant Press, will we have to put all the HTML code on GitHub? Or since it's HTML, it's already open for everyone to see so it seems like it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, the product of running a GPL code does not have to be GPL-licensed. See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not modifying the source code of the software you won't need to publish the source code.

InstantPress is a CMS software similar to WordPress

Comment: You also don’t have to provide the source when you modify it. You only need to provide the source when you provide (distribute) the software, no matter if modified or not. But with the GPL, running it on a server doesn’t count as distribution.